# Emacs Haskell Intero problems

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, intero

I am writing the Haskell programs with the package `readline`. When I use the   Intero and cabal file to autoinstall the package, it reports the error and can't recognize the package. while I can install it with `stack` perfectly. below is part of my cabal file:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
  other-modules:
      Paths_ch24
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , directory
    , bytestring
    , readline
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

So my question is whether it is a `bug` of `Intero` or just something I misoperate?

Comment: I had some issues with Emacs and intero in the past due to incompatible versions. Perhaps, check that your emacs intero package is updated.

Comment: While It's already the newest version of `intero`.

Comment: To avoid confusion: the `intero` you install with `stack` is one thing, the `intero` emacs package you install under `emacs` is another.

Comment: how do I know my intero from which? stack or emacs package?